# What diagrams to include in Wilson's Approach?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, feynman-diagrams, effective-field-theory

In the Wilson's approach to renormalization we split the field into two parts; a high momentum part and a low momentum part. We then integrate out the high momentum terms. Consider the case of $\phi^3$ theory and the two diagrams below:

[image]

The dashed (red) lines represent the high momenta field and the solid (black) the low momenta. It is clear that diagram $A$ contributes to the $C_4\phi^4$ in the new effective Lagrangian by making a change to the $C_4$.

I am confused however about diagram B. Does it contribute to the $C_6\phi^6$ term in the effective Lagrangian or is it a result of the $C_6\phi^6$ term.

I.e. When finding the contributions to the new coupling constants do we only include diagrams of the form A or do we have to also include the form B?

**Edit**

Colour coded version of B

[image]

Comment: Hint: are you sure you should get a closed loop for the slow fields, knowing that you do not average over them ?

Comment: @Adam I would say yes, since in B averaging over the 3 dashed lines means we put them to zero length - does it not? Otherwise I can't possibly see what $B$ must go to?

Comment: As you say, you can shrink the dashed line to zero. But why have you linked two of the black lines together ?

Comment: @Adam I have color coded the diagram. If I take all dashed (red) lines to zero then all four vertexes must meet at the same point. I am not sure which two lines you mean.

Comment: For B, you have a black line linking two vertices. My question is : why have you linked these two vertices with a black line, knowing that you do not average (integrate out) the slow fields.

Comment: @Adam Oh OK. I think this is the crux of my question. I have included this diagram because it is allowed - i.e. given the types of vertices present in the Lagrangian when we split the field;  $\hat \phi \phi^2$, $\phi^2\hat \phi$ etc. we can form this diagram. No weather or not we have to explicitly integrate out the slow field in it or whether it contributes by some other means is what this question is trying to get at.  You seem to be indicating that we do not include it.

Comment: Put it another way : why do you have linked these two black legs of these two vertices,  and not the black legs of the other vertices ? Clearly something wrong is happening here ;)

Comment: @Adam Sorry I still don't get what you are asking. I have uploaded a new diagram (with labels :) ).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To implement Wilson's RG for a $\phi^3$ theory, we split the field into a slow $\phi$ and a fast $\hat \phi$ component. There are two kinds of interesting vertices (contributing to the renormalization of the slow field action) :  $\phi_1 \hat\phi_1 \hat\phi_1$ and $\phi_1 \phi_1 \hat\phi_1$ (the number corresponding to the space-time/internal indices).

The diagram A of the OP corresponds to (averages over the fast fields only)
$$\langle\phi_1 \hat\phi_{1} \hat\phi_{1}\phi_2 \hat\phi_{2} \hat\phi_{2}\phi_3 \hat\phi_{3} \hat\phi_{3}\phi_4 \hat\phi_{4} \hat\phi_{4} \rangle=\phi_{1}\phi_2\phi_3\phi_4  \langle \hat\phi_{1} \hat\phi_{1}\hat\phi_{2} \hat\phi_{2} \hat\phi_{3} \hat\phi_{3}\hat\phi_{4} \hat\phi_{4} \rangle. $$
Here $\langle \hat\phi_{1} \hat\phi_{1}\hat\phi_{2} \hat\phi_{2} \hat\phi_{3} \hat\phi_{3}\hat\phi_{4} \hat\phi_{4} \rangle$ corresponds to the dashed red closed loop of left diagram A of the OP. On the other hand, the (black, full) legs of the diagram correspond to the slow fields $\phi_{1}$, $\phi_2$, $\phi_3$ and $\phi_4$, which are not connected, since they are not integrated over.

In momentum space, thanks to the fact that the incoming momenta are much slower than the flowing mometum in the loop, one can approximate $\langle \hat\phi_{1} \hat\phi_{1}\hat\phi_{2} \hat\phi_{2} \hat\phi_{3} \hat\phi_{3}\hat\phi_{4} \hat\phi_{4} \rangle\propto \delta(1+2)\delta(1+3)\delta(1+4) $ and thus shrink the loop to a single point (corresponding to a $\phi^4$ vertex).

Concerning diagram B, using the same color code, we see that this diagram is made using also the second kind of vertex (that we didn't use for diagram A) :
$$\langle\phi_1 \phi_1 \hat\phi_1\phi_2 \hat\phi_2 \hat\phi_2\phi_3 \hat\phi_3 \hat\phi_3\phi_4 \phi_4 \hat\phi_4\rangle=\phi_1 \phi_1\phi_2\phi_3\phi_4 \phi_4\langle \hat\phi_1 \hat\phi_2 \hat\phi_2 \hat\phi_3 \hat\phi_3 \hat\phi_4\rangle.$$

Here $\langle \hat\phi_1 \hat\phi_2 \hat\phi_2 \hat\phi_3 \hat\phi_3 \hat\phi_4\rangle$ corresponds to the three red dashed line of the OP, while the six slow field should correspond to six legs. The OP's problem is that there should not be a full black (or blue) line in diagram B : the slow fields are not integrated over, so the slow fields legs of the vertices should not be connected.

By the same argument than before $\langle \hat\phi_1 \hat\phi_2 \hat\phi_2 \hat\phi_3 \hat\phi_3 \hat\phi_4\rangle\propto\delta(1+2)\delta(1+3)\delta(1+4)$ and thus diargam B corresponds to a $\phi^6$ interaction.